# How can I bring to front an object in SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

Is there any way to get objects to foregorund in surfaceView.

for example:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(...);
canvas.drawText(...);
```

If I do that text appeared on bitmap. How can I reverse it without redrawing

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Call `canvas.drawText(...)` before `canvas.drawBitmap(...);` maybe ?

Comment: **without redrawing**

Comment: if your canvas draw on some view then you can do  view.bringTofornt()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas just encapsulates bitmap object and bitmap only saves colour of pixel at some position, it doesn't save separate layers. It's like to draw in MSPaint. So you can't change the Z-order of your primitives on canvas.  However, why don't you just change the order of commands?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to bring elements front and back. You are trying to alter the Z-order of the elements here and this is not possible or there is no direct method in Android. All you can do is arrange them in the layout and enable and disable views so that it will give you the same effect.
You can use `addView()` or `setVisibility(View.Visible)` to bring bring elements back and front.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code.

```
//SurfaceView class
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    MainThread thread;

    public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("N", "Changed");

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("N", "Created");
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("N", "Destroyed");
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // try again shutting down the thread
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (event.getY() > getHeight() - 50) {
                thread.setRunning(false);
                ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
            } else {
                Log.d("N", "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}

//MainThread class

public class MainThread extends Thread {

    // flag to hold game state
    private boolean running;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private MainGamePanel gamePanel;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long tickCount = 0L;
        Log.d("N", "Starting game loop");
        while (running) {
            tickCount++;
            // update game state
            // render state to the screen
        }
        Log.d("N", "Game loop executed " + tickCount + " times");
    }


}
//Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```